# Objective-C, App's Web service calls works over wifi but not over mobile data

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

I've a iOS project which I got from some other people, I've to add some features to this app which makes some web service calls.

I'm using UNIRest library and the web service calls works over wifi, but not over mobile data. I don't think its a timeout issue, because when making the web service call I'm instantly getting response as null.

Another topic on StackOverflow said to use https, but I'm already using https. I been trying to figure out what's the problem for hours now, but had no luck. Are there some settings in the build settings or some where which might cause this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

I tried NSURLConnection

```
NSString *aurl = [CHeckForDevice stringByAppendingString:self.app.uniqueAppId];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:aurl];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     if (error){
         NSLog(@"Error,%@", [error localizedDescription]);
     } else {
         NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
     }
 }];
```

and it prints

```
Error,The Internet connection appears to be offline.
```

I just created a new Dummy project and and it is working on mobile data as well but not in this project.

Comment: check this   http://osxdaily.com/2015/09/24/ios-9-cellular-data-not-working-troubleshooting/

Comment: Sorry, not helpful.

Comment: Check this https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05042016a

Answer (score 0):

```
HeisenBerg 

      you need to text in other network because i was facing same error . sometimes network is ok but we can't get any responds that's why you need to check other network . definitely you get responds change network . 2G network have same problem but 3G network is working fine .
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Use cellular data was turned off for my app.

From apple support page,

To view the cellular data usage for your apps, tap Settings > Cellular. You can turn cellular data on or off for each app. Contact your carrier if you have questions about your cellular data usage.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try this, add into your pList file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```